# View File name only in AsyncFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, .net

When i upload file using `AsyncFileUpload` path view like image contain C:\fakepath{filename}.
[image: File Path]

note: my correct path not contain (fakepath word).

Comment: I would like to explain that initially in early days it was sent to the server but later on due to advancement in the Internet field, that path was being used to hack the computer.
Hence now the location of the folder of the file on the user’s machine is not sent to the server.

Comment: mainly i work local, how solve this problem?

Comment: i want to view file name only

Comment: share ur code what u tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover it is related to browser security. If i try to open my page in other browser like FireFox problem is solved so it is not problem.
Tutorial help my: [Link1](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?267159-Chrome-shows-always-quot-c-fakepath-quot-in-upload-field-instead-of-the-right-path), [link2](https://davidwalsh.name/fakepath), [link3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68471/the-image-uploader-shows-fakepath-as-path-when-using-chrome)